# Add launchers dir to the PATH

Tags: ide, jetbrains-ide

While I am installing IDEs from JetBrains, in installation options I can "add launchers dir to the PATH", what does it mean?

Cannot understand what does it mean exactly.

Answer (score 24):

This option allows adding `<ide install dir>/bin` to your system `%PATH%` so that you can start the launcher from any folder by just entering `idea` (`webstorm`, etc) in cmd console

Comment: but without this option i have link/launcher(or how it calls on desktop) and entering it from this link(without opening ide/bin/intellij.exe to start IDE)

Comment: desktop shortcuts allow launching application from desktop; adding launcher to %PATH% allows running it from command line - these are different things

Comment: @lena so should we add launchers dir to the PATH and what are the pros and cons? say, I decide not to add now during installation and leave that option checkbox unticked, how do you add this to PATH in future?

Comment: in the way you usually do this on Windows - by editing system environment variables:)